# Is it possible to pass Cassandra cluster name (defined in config) to save() with spark cassandra connector

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

So the read works fine as per documentation:

```
val cql = new org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSQLContext(sc)
cql.setConf("cluster-src/spark.cassandra.connection.host", "1.1.1.1")
cql.setConf("cluster-dst/spark.cassandra.connection.host", "2.2.2.2")

...

var df = cql.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .option("table", "my_table")
  .option("keyspace", "my_keyspace")
  .option("cluster", "cluster-src")
  .load()
```

But it is not clear how to pass the destination cluster name to the save counterpart. This obviously does not work, it just tries to connect to the local spark host:

```
df.write
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .option("table", "my_table")
  .option("keyspace", "my_keyspace")
  .option("cluster", "cluster-dst")
  .save()
```

**Update:**

Found a workaround but it is kind of ugly. So instead of:

```
.option("cluster", "cluster-dst")
```

use:

```
.option("spark_cassandra_connection_host", cql.getConf("cluster-dst/spark.cassandra.connection.host")
```

Comment: Looks like a bug. Can you please file a JIRA here: https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/secure/RapidBoard.jspa?rapidView=18&projectKey=SPARKC